# Errors using maven-bundle-plugin Embed-Dependency

Tags: maven, osgi

I have a Maven project that's building fine, and I'm attempting to add a reference to twitter4j.

So I add this to the pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[2.2,)</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I build (mvn clean install) I get:

```
[ERROR] Error building bundle net.stevex.tweetfetcher:tweetfetcher-bundle:bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT : Unresolved references to [twitter4j] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot]: [net/stevex/tweetfetcher/impl/TweetFetcherImpl.class]
```

This makes sense .. the twitter4j package isn't embedded in the bundle.  So I add an Embed-Dependency to the maven-bundle-plugin's instructions:

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
```

And now when I build, I get:

```
[ERROR] Error building bundle net.stevex.tweetfetcher:tweetfetcher-bundle:bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT : Unresolved references to [dalvik.system, javax.crypto, javax.crypto.spec, javax.management, javax.management.openmbean, org.apache.commons.logging, org.apache.log4j, org.slf4j.impl, twitter4j.internal.http.alternative] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot, Jar:twitter4j-core-2.2.3.jar]: [twitter4j/internal/logging/CommonsLoggingLogger.class, twitter4j/internal/logging/Log4JLoggerFactory.class, twitter4j/auth/OAuthToken.class, twitter4j/internal/http/HttpClientFactory.class, twitter4j/auth/OAuthAuthorization.class, twitter4j/internal/logging/Log4JLogger.class, twitter4j/conf/ConfigurationBase.class, twitter4j/TwitterAPIMonitor.class, twitter4j/internal/logging/CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory.class, twitter4j/management/APIStatisticsOpenMBean.class, twitter4j/internal/logging/Logger.class]
```

I don't understand why the twitter4j classes are missing, and I don't understand the references to dalvik.system, javax.crypto, etc.  What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the twitter4j project requires all of the packages listed in the error list.  When you use  it does not include all transitive dependencies.  There is an Embed Transitive instruction for the maven-bundle-plugin that will embed all transitive dependencies

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency> 
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

However, this kind of defeats the purpose of OSGi.  This leaves you with two options that I know of:

1. Search for the packages in the second in the [SpringSource EBR](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/).  You simply enter the package name in the search box, and the results will include the xml for your POM file.  The SpringSource bundles will include references to other bundles in the EBR, eliminating the problem of transitive dependencies.
2. Use the bundle-all goal of the maven-bundle-plugin.  This goal will run the maven bundle plugin for every dependency of your project, and place the resulting bundles into your target directory.  You could then install these bundles into your local repository.

I would recommend using option 1 for as many of the bundles as you can find, then defaulting to option 2 when SpringSource doesn't have them.

Comment: The packages that twitter4j was looking for aren't required, so I added import statements to the Import-Package with them marked as optional:  twitter4j.internal.http.alternative;resolution:=optional (etc).